# Silverlight 4 OOB Updating

Tags: silverlight-4.0, versioning, auto-update, out-of-browser

I've built a silverlight 4 app that is soon to be deployed but I'm having some trouble with the updating.

The versioning number system I'm using is

- **Major** = year
- **Minor** = month
- **Revison** = day
- **Build** = build number for the day.

Which is updated to the day we push an update out.

Now according to [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/vblasberg/archive/2010/06/12/silverlight-oob-checkanddownloadupdateasync.aspx) SilverLight will only grab an update if there is a change to Major/Minor.

Is there anyway around this?
If I have to change the version numbering system that's fine too.

Cheers
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue where IE wouldn't get the update unless the cache is cleared so I added the version number to the object in the html/aspx. Like this:

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/MyApp.xap?v=1.2.3.4"/>
```

Now IE gets the latest every time the version changes. This could be anything, I just chose the version number.